# Python: Script to detect data Hazards

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on a school project to write a program that detects Read-After-Write data dependencies in assembly instructions. I have a list of lists containing instructions.

One such example is a list such as
line1 = [[ld a8,0x8910] [mul a3,a2,8] [shl a3,a3,4] [add a3,a3,a8]]

Here the last add instruction depends on result of shift left (shl) which in-turn depends on result of mul intsruction.

I would like my code to output dependency as {mul -> sh -> add}

Another example: line2 =  [ [add a3,a2,a1] [sub a4,a5,a6] [add a9,a2,a4]]
output: {add -> add} {sub -> add}

I want to remove the instruction opcodes to get line1 = [[**a8**,*0x8910*] [**a3**,*a2,8*] [**a3**,*a3,4*] [**a3**,*a3,a8*]] 
and then extracted destination operands into a dst_list = [**a8, a3, a3, a3**} and source operands into another list as src_list = [ *0x8910*, [*a2,8*], [*a3,4*], [*a3,a8*] ]. I'm thinking of taking nth item from src_list and compare with 0 to n-1 items of dst_list and output indices when they match. Finally use some dictionary to output instructions corresponding to my indices. Is my approach correct? Can anybody help me on how to achieve this in python?

So far I've tried:

```
 dest = re.findall( r'\[(?=([a-z0-9.]+))',str(line))
 src = re.findall( r'\,(?=([a-z0-9]+))', str(line))
 for i in dest:
                    dst_list.append([i])
 for j in src:
                    src_list.append(j)

#psuedo code to find hazards
for nth src_item in src_list:
     for 0 to n-1 dst_items in dst_list:
          if src_list[src_item] == dst_list[dst_item]
              OUTPUT dst_item -> src_item
```

The re.findall above gives me a single list with all destination operands and another list with source operands (I need list of lists with 2 src arguments of each instruction in a single list).

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Could you clarify that last bit? I'm having a hard time following what it its you need, and what you are getting. also, unless you are using some kind of syntax replacer, that doesn't look like valid python code.

Comment: The last part is just a pseudo code. The re.findall returns a single list src_list = [ 0x8910, a2, 8, a3, 4, a3, a8 ] instead of [0x8910, [a2,8], [a3,4], [a3,a8]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let's first assume that your assembly instructions will have consistent formatting, and that they are in a list of strings, because otherwise you'll have to do a bunch of preprocessing anyway, and should be handling the op code and instruction parsing then.

```
[op_code dest,src1,src2,...,srcn]
```

ex:

```
line1 = ["ld a8,0x8910","mul a3,a2,8","shl a3,a3,4","add a3,a3,a8"]
```

With that we can do some python magic and not even worry about regex.

```
def instruction_reader(op_string):
    opcode,values = op_string.split(" ")
    values_list = values.split(',')
    dest = values_list[0]
    src = values_list[1:]

    return (opcode,dest,src)
```

With that you can now put the data in the correct buckets through some list iterators

```
list_of_all = [instruction_reader(item) for item in line1]
opcodes = [op[0] for op in list_of_all]
dests = [dest[1] for dest in list_of_all]
srcs = [src[2] for src in list_of_all]
```

Now you just have to do the comparisons between the srcs and dests to find dependencies.

```
dep_list = []
for i,dest in enumerate(dests):
    for src in srcs:
        if dest in src:
            dep_list.append(opcodes[i])
```

which could be reduced into a list comprehension

```
dep_list = [opcodes[i] for i,dest in enumerate(dests) for src in srcs if dest in src]
```

**Aside:** Yes there are much prettier ways to do this in python, but I figured something that's a bit easier to read/parse would be better in this case.

Comment: You assume the formatting is `[op_code src,dest1,dest2,...]` but in the `instruction_reader()`, the variable `src=["dest1","dest2",...]` and `dest=src`.

Comment: @Yep_It's_Me whoops, you're correct, thanks, will fix.  Read his explanation wrong.

Comment: @JeffLangemeier: As you pointed out, the instructions doesn't always have a dest, src, src format. Some instructions may have only one src and some even 3. There are couple of instructions that doesn't take any argumnets. Conditionally extracting opcodes is a duanting of a task. Any easier way to handle this?

Comment: @Mohan the way I set it up it isn't conditional; essentially, as long as you have at least 1 source, this method will work.  I'll add something on "zero src/dest" but it should be pretty easy to use if/elses to clean that up.

Comment: (missed the edit time on comment): Further, any instruction that has 0 for src/dest would probably need to be counted differently anyway.  An assembly instruction that doesn't take any src/dest, such as an increment register instruction will have an internal dependancy on itself.  A good example of this would be in the Freescale 16bit MCU assembly where you can increment a specific register through INCX or INCY (X or Y register, respectively).